Hegel’s philosophy of history. What if?

"The topic of history has been treated frequently in modern European
philosophy. A long, largely German, tradition of thought looks at
history as a total and comprehensible process of events, structures,
and processes, for which the philosophy of history can serve as an
interpretive tool. This approach, speculative and meta-historical,
aims to discern large, embracing patterns and directions in the
unfolding of human history, persistent notwithstanding the erratic
back-and-forth of particular historical developments. Modern
philosophers raising this set of questions about the large direction
and meaning of history include Vico, Herder, and Hegel.
Hegel incorporates a deeper historicism into his philosophical
theories than his predecessors or successors. He regards the
relationship between “objective” history and the subjective
development of the individual consciousness (“spirit”) as an intimate
one; this is a central thesis in his Phenomenology of Spirit (1807).
And he views it to be a central task for philosophy to comprehend its
place in the unfolding of history. "
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/history/

From SpaceX Starship's remarkable "catch landing" to numerous discoveries in pharmacology, medicine, chemistry. We are all watching and experiencing the rapid adaptation of AI technologies in scientific research.
What if at some point an Artificial Intelligence, after examining trillions of data points in known human history, concludes beyond reasonable doubt that there are patterns in human history that would be impossible within a physicalist's view of our reality?
Would we have to rewrite philosophy as we know, or do we already have a philosophical foundation for further development?

We have already revised philosophical point of views due to new scientific discoveries: heliocentrism, Galileo, Darwin.

What if wishes were horses? Would beggars get to ride? How do you imagine answering a hypothetical   about a future situation we know almost nothing about based on a conclusion of AI we know even less about? If God comes down from heaven and  names our errors we'd probably have to rewrite something. Is that informative?

Actually, I doubt one could conceive of history without assuming it is composed of social changes and events, themselves composed of individuals' mental events as their fundamental building blocks. So, there's no need for an AI: natural intelligence is enough to rule out any human history that would just be made of elementary particles, which I take as what you mean by "a physicalist's view of our reality".

And that is the main issue with any form of historicism: the neglect of human agency.

@Olivier5 - "A bad dancer's balls get in the way"

In addition to @Lowri's excellent answer it is also worth observing that our known human history is written by fallible humans.
Much of the historical account is enormously controversial if not frequently bordering to the fantastical. Given the fact that much of Western history is written in the Christian tradition, it would not be fully surprising for an AI to conclude that Hegel's teleological view was warranted...
Bias in the training data is a known problem in artificial intelligence.

You posit that:

[something], after examining trillions of data points in known human history, concludes beyond reasonable doubt that there are patterns in human history that would be impossible within a physicalist's view of our reality?

If that is the case, a physicalist following the same evidence would simply reject the theories that are inconsistent with that evidence. It doesn't matter what the [something] is that does that examining. You've suggested AI, but that is a red herring.
Nothing in your scenario distinguishes it from a scenario where scientists simply observe something that conflicts with a given theory. That is a run-of-the-mill occurrence and is accomodated within the standard theory and practice of science.
It is also unclear how the scenario is "impossible within a physicalist's view of our reality" given that the conclusion flows from examination of "data points." A physicalist's view of reality is based on there being data points to examine.

Can you accommodate Hegel as a "run-of-the-mill occurrence" ?

@TheMatrixEquation-balance I think this answer is merely comparing the pattern in your example to a "run-of-the-mill occurrence" of conflicting data in the turbulent history of science. Your question in no way suggests that this alleged pattern in your example affirms Hegel's attempts to discover meaning or direction in history. Hegel's view that history moves towards a realisation of human freedom is not causally connected to the pattern. This is not clear in the question, though it could be understood from the title of the question.
